# Get PageReference from Page.variable

Tags: apex, pagereference

I am trying to dynamically set a PageReference based on a variable.

```
String pageId = '0664A000000AAaA';
String pageName = [SELECT Name FROM ApexPage WHERE Id =: pageId ].Name;
PageReference pdf = Page.pageName;
```

Currently, this is taking Page.pageName as literal and returns "Page not found: Page.pageName"

How can I dynamically set this page reference depending on the variable I pass as the page name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also don't forgot about having namespace, you need to pass the relative page URL to generate the pagereference.

Here is an example:

```
ApexPage apexPage =  [SELECT Name, NamespacePrefix FROM ApexPage 
    WHERE Name = 'YourPageName' ];

String pageName = apexPage.Name;
// append namespace if page is packaged
if(String.isNotEmpty(apexPage.NamespacePrefix)) {
    pageName = apexPage.NamespacePrefix+'__' + pageName;
}
String partialPageUrl = '/apex/' + pageName;
PageReference pdf = new PageReference(partialPageUrl);
System.debug(pdf.getUrl());
```

Comment: Ahh perfect! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!